# Перспектива использования WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Всем доброго дня!

Думаю, этот вопрос много раз уже поднимался. Меня интересует положение дел на сегодня.

Скажите, пожалуйста, есть ли смысл сейчас осваивать WPF? Каковы перспективы данной технологии? Насколько я понял, изучать WinForms нет никакого смысла, если проект сложный.

Comment: WPF это прежде всего язык разметки XAML, а он в свою очередь используется в UWP, Xamarin.Forms. Так что зная WPF легко начать писать приложения для смартфонов и планшетов.

Comment: @Bulson приоритетней xamarin native, потому что у Xamarin Forms возможностей мало - привязка сразу к 3ем платформам ..

Comment: @ParanoidPanda все течет, все меняется. Эта технология достаточно активно развивается, так что ваша ремарка скоро устареет.

Comment: WinForms смело можно проходить мимо. WPF застывший проект, но если уж выбирать между WinForms и WPF то разница колоссальна. А вот будущее WPF...мир развивается под лозунгом "модное лучше хорошего" и потому всякие шатания то в сторону js, то в сторону кастрированных вариаций WPF, а сам WPF чуть ли не заброшен в развитии (что не мешает ему быть замечательной тулзой для создания UI)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WPF дает огромный спектр возможностей для работы с UI, начиная от кастомизации совершенно любых UI контролов, заканчивая описанием своих (`UserControl`). Но следует понимать что и UI потребляет определенное количество ресурсов. WinForms советую изучать для ознакомления, не помешает, иногда проще наверстать и сделать быстрей на WinForms легковесную поделку для работы например с визуальным представление сериализации/десериализации каких либо данных, или работа с бд - обработка и представление. Где приоритет на алгоритм и быстродействие, чем на визуальную составляющую.

Comment: Быстро наверстать и сделать поделку можно и в WPF. Достаточно использовать `<Canvas/>` в качестве корневого элемента, и тогда подобно WinForms можно бросать мышкой контролы, выставлять их размеры и расстояния между ними. И подобно WinForms программировать на основе событий + можно задействовать привязки. Никакого преимущества у WinForms перед WPF нет.

Comment: @Bulson вы пропустили слово "легковесную". При всех недостатках WinForms, включая ее возраст и заброшенные баги, которые уже никогда не пофиксят, два преимущества все таки есть: низкий порог вхождения и легковесность, по сравнению с WPF. Формы работают почти на чистом WinAPI, поэтому расход дополнительных ресурсов минимален. Для интерфейса настройки служебных сервисов самое то, а лишнее время лучше потратить на сами сервисы. ИМХО разумеется.

Comment: @rdorn, согласен, про эту сторону вопроса я действительно забыл. Вы правы.

Answer (score 3):

> Скажите, пожалуйста, есть ли смысл сейчас осваивать WPF?

Есть!

> Каковы перспективы данной технологии?

перспективы что она будет единственной и откажутся от WinForms, как от устаревшей.

> Насколько я понял, изучать WinForms нет никакого смысла, если проект сложный.

WinForms изучать нету смысла если в проэктах с которыми работаешь важно GUI составляющая(интефейс то есть).

И наоборот. Есть смысл если будешь работать в проэктах где это не важно.

Разобратся с WPF будет сложнее. Но это того стоит. (хотя ради справедливости, скажу что сам я до него так и не добрался.)

Comment: В проекте, над которым я работаю, используется слабое железо. Сам интерфейс не так важен - обычный ввод/вывод информации.
Однако меня привлекает использование MVVM, что должно положительно сказаться на дальнейшей поддержке программы. Да и работать с XAML удобно (знаю, знаю, не всем он нравится).

Так что я определился с выбором технологии. Может быть потом буду плеваться)) Кто знает)